# Platformio ci libraries not found

Tags: c++, arduino, travis-ci, platformio

I am new to embedded development and I am stuck at an problem that I can't figure out by reading the documentation. I am developing an IOT project as part of an school assignment. I have a github repository with the source code of the project and I am trying to setup Travis CI. Everything worked fine when all the code lived in the main.cpp file but after moving parts of the code to separate classes in the `lib` directory the build kept failing. The problem is that it doesn't find my classes.

English is not my native language so it could be that I am misunderstanding something in the documentation. Is there somebody that knows what I am doing wrong? I would appreciate any help or suggestions maybe an part of the documentation that I should take an closer look at, Thanks in advance!

An link to my repository [WaterUp-PlantPot](https://github.com/INF1I/WaterUp-PlantPot)

```
src/main.cpp:9:82: fatal error: MQTT.h: No such file or directory
#include <MQTT.h>
```

My directory structure

```
|--lib
|  |--MQTT
|  |  |- MQTT.cpp
|  |  |- MQTT.h 
|  |--Sensors
|  |  |- Sensors.cpp
|  |  |- Sensors.h
|- platformio.ini
|- .travis.yml
|--src
   |- main.c
```

The main.cpp file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MQTT.h>
#include <Sensors.h>
MQTT mqtt; // Create an new MQTT object for communication with the broker.
Sensors sensors; // Create an new  Sensors object for taking measurements about the pot state.

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200); // Start serial communication for sending debug messages to the serial port.
    delay(10);
    mqtt.setup( &sensors ); // Setup the mqtt library.

}

void loop()
{
    mqtt.mqttConnect(); // Connect to the broker if the connection is lost.
    mqtt.runLoop(); // Run the main program.
}
```

My travis.yml file:

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"
sudo: false
cache:
    directories:
        - "~/.platformio"
env:
    - PLATFORMIO_CI_SRC=./src/main.cpp

install:
    - pip install -U platformio
    - platformio lib -g install "Adafruit MQTT Library"
    - platformio lib -g install Streaming
script:
     - platformio ci --board=huzzah
```